# React componentDidUpdate running before prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the **CryptoHistoricGraph** component in app.js, and I'm passing `this.state.coinPrices` as the prop for this element

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import CryptoSelect from './components/cryptoSelectComponent'
import CryptoHistoricGraph from './components/cryptoHistoricGraphComponent'

interface IProps {
}

interface IState {
  selectedCoin?: selectOption;
  coinPrices: priceObject[]
}

interface selectOption {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

interface priceObject {
  timestamp: string;
  price: number;
}

class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedCoin: undefined,
      coinPrices: []
    }
  }

  getCryptoHistoric() {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/historicaldata?timePeriod=24h&coin=' + this.state.selectedCoin?.value
    axios.get(url)
      .then(async res => {
        if (res.data) {
          const coinPrices = await Object.entries(res.data.price).map(([key, value]) => {
            const priceObject: priceObject = {
              timestamp: key,
              price: Number(value)
            }
            return priceObject
          })
          this.setState({ coinPrices: coinPrices })
        }
      })
  }

  handleCryptoChange = (cryptoSelected: selectOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedCoin: cryptoSelected }, () => {
      this.getCryptoHistoric()
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" >
        <CryptoSelect onSelectCrypto={this.handleCryptoChange.bind(this)} />
        <p> Selected coin: {this.state.selectedCoin?.value} </p>
        <CryptoHistoricGraph historicData={this.state.coinPrices} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In the component, I want to do some data filtering, and I call this function after the `componentDidUpdate`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

interface IProps {
    historicData: priceObject[];
}

interface IState {
    yLabel: number[];
    xLabel: string[];
}

interface priceObject {
    timestamp: string;
    price: number;
}

export default class CryptoHistoricGraph extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            yLabel: [],
            xLabel: []
        }
    }

    filterData(historicData: priceObject[]) {
        const yLabel: number[] = []
        const xLabel: string[] = []

        historicData.forEach(element => {
            yLabel.push(element.price)
            xLabel.push(element.timestamp)
        });

        this.setState({
            yLabel: yLabel,
            xLabel: xLabel
        })
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: { historicData: priceObject[]; }) {
        if (prevProps.historicData !== this.props.historicData) {
            console.log('Prop change')
            this.filterData(this.props.historicData);
        } else {
            console.log('Prop dont change')
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            {/* <Line
                data={this.data}
            /> */}
        </div >;
    }
}
```

So, I expect to have some console.log like: **Prop change** and after **Prop dont change**, because the componentdidupdate should run one time when prop change and another one when the state of yLabel and xLabel change, but instead I'm getting

[image]

This happens every time I change the prop.

How can I avoid this first update?

**EDIT:**

In every update, I'm getting this props and states, the first line before and the second after the update

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The last `Prop dont change` it's triggered by your function `filterData` that sets the state

Comment: Yeah, I want this, but I don't know why the first Prop dont change it's triggered. Because neither the props or the state of the component change in this first trigger

Comment: Why don't you `console.log` to see have have changed? It seems to be the  <CryptoHistoricGraph historicData={this.state.coinPrices} />

Comment: Yeah, the props are changing when you select the coin

Comment: Probably, look at `historicData: Array(0)` then `historicData: Array(289)`, this triggered a render in your `CryptoHistoricGraph` component